# Placeholder Photo Not Appearing on Null URL in Search - Android, Kotlin, Glide

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-glide

I'm using Glide in an Android, Kotlin, Jetpack project.  When the photos are loading, the `DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE` appears.  However if one of the movies that is returned has a `null` value for an image URL, no image appears and the card shrinks down to the size of only the title.  I'm trying to set it so the `DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE` will appear if there is a `null` value for the movie poster url.

Setting a placeholder or an error image does not appear to be working.

Image part of the MovieCard composable

```
movie.posterPath?.let { url ->
            val image = loadPicture(url = url, defaultImage = DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE).value
            image?.let { img ->
                Image(
                    bitmap = img.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = "Movie Projector",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(450.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                )
            }
```

ImageUtils.kt

```
    const val DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE = R.drawable.movie_placeholder
    const val POSTER_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"

@Composable
fun loadPicture(
    url: String,
    @DrawableRes defaultImage: Int
): MutableState<Bitmap?> {

    val bitmapState: MutableState<Bitmap?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

    Glide.with(LocalContext.current)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(defaultImage)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                bitmapState.value = resource
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            }

        })

    Glide.with(LocalContext.current)
        .asBitmap()
        .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500$url")
        .error(R.drawable.space_dog_laika1)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                bitmapState.value = resource
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            }

        })

    return bitmapState
}
```

Comment: You want to do this using Glide only? There is popular library [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) which can help you fetch images from internet and also offers Compose integration.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the image piece of the movie card in an if/else statement.  I'm not sure if this is best practice or the most terse solution, but it worked.

```
if (movie.posterPath != null) {
                movie.posterPath?.let { url ->
                    val image = loadPicture(url = url, defaultImage = DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE).value
                    image?.let { img ->
                        Image(
                            bitmap = img.asImageBitmap(),
                            contentDescription = "Movie Poster",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(450.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                        )
                    }
                }
            } else {
                val image: Painter = painterResource(id = DEFAULT_MOVIE_IMAGE)
                Image(
                    painter = image,
                    contentDescription = "Film Projector",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(450.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                )
            }
```